# Facebook Get Started Button not rendering for new user(non developer)

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

Facebook get started button is not rendering for users who are not added in app developer account.

I can see get started button working for users having any role assigned to them in app developer console. But same is not working for general users

P.S as per FB developer doc I have taken care of all the points mentioned below

1 -My app is not in development mode. it is public and available to all.

2 -Webhook postback is properly configured and is working fine with users who are registered as developer in FB app developer console(developer can see "get started button" on messenger and web as well).

3 - User are first time user(Not have done any conversation with my FB app before).

in-shot Normal FB users or new FB users are not getting "GET started button" on there FB messenger or on web(www.messenger.com)

Comment: Did you submit your app for review yet ...? That is necessary, before normal users can interact with it.

Comment: @CBroe ya I have submitted it for review, below are the list of approved items

1-email

2-public_profile

3-user_friends

Do I need any other item to get approved in order to get "get started button" working for normal users

Comment: one has to submit app under messenger ->setting

select page_messaging put notes and submit for review.
It might take two our three days to get approved.